# c++ String returning with an extra char

Tags: c++, string

I have tested my program and am certain right before being returned the string in my function equals "card001". But the returned value equals "card0011". I have no idea how this even happens. Help me before I lose my mind. ;)

```
std::string function_cardTexture(int card) {

    //removes the last 1
    card = card - 10000;

    int ctr = 0;

    card = floor(card / 10);

    std::cout << card << std::endl;

    //turn int card into a string
    std::string a = static_cast<std::ostringstream*>(&(std::ostringstream() << card))->str();

    //combines card and string a into one string
    std::string nametext = "card00" + a;

    std::cout << nametext << std::endl;

    return (nametext);
}

void function_Battle(tempPlayer &Player, tempCard &card001) {

    if (Player.Start == true) {
        //Draw hand
        for (int i = 0; i < Player.numDrawn; i++) {

            int x = rand() % Player.deckSize + 0; ;

            Player.Hand[i] = Player.Deck[x];
            Player.Discarded[x] = 1;
        }

        Player.Start = false;
    }
    std::map<std::string, tempCard> Vars;
    //draw hand
    for (int i = 0; i < Player.handMax;i++) {
        if (Player.Hand[i] != 0) {
            sf::RectangleShape Card(sf::Vector2f(80.0f, 128.0f));

            std::string nametext = function_cardTexture(Player.Hand[i]);
            std::cout << nametext;
            sf::Texture texture = Vars[nametext].Art;

            Card.setTexture(&texture);
            window.draw(Card);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I got `card001` on my machine.  I passed in 10010 as the argument to function_cardTexture.  Note that `floor` is unnecessary since card is an int.

Comment: There is something called [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string). Are you sure the '1' is from `nametext`? When you printed it, you didn't print anything after it such as a line break or a space, so if something else printed a '1' later it would look like it was from `nametext`. There's also really no need to make all your function names start with `function_`, since it's quite easy to tell a function from something else.

Comment: I tried hard coding 10010 just to be sure and I still got `card0011`. Just to be clear I do git `card001` in the function but it's returned as `card0011`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is how you're printing things out without a newline in the function_Battle() function, so you're likely "smashing together" your new value with an old one.  If you replace your main function with just a loop with clearer printing of values, you can see you don't have a problem:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d1e4f51643b84b9

That link will go to an online compiler where I just replaced the calling function with a loop that makes numbers.  It even supplies a negative one.